# Printing set elements in python

Tags: python, set

I have this set:

```
my_set = {'1': {'a'},
          '2': {'b'},
          '3': {'c'}
          }
```

I need to print the number with the associated letter in the same order as I have defined my_set, then I coded this:

```
for i in my_set:
    print (i)
```

but I got only the numbers and after several runs the numbers appears in different sequences like this:

```
3
2
1

1
3
2
```

...

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: A set and a dictionary are examples of hash tables. They have no order. A set has 'keys'. A dictionary has 'key-value pairs'. You have a dictionary. In both cases, the keys are unordered. In your code, i iterates over the keys. If you want order, then use a list. If you want the output order to be the same as the order that you added the keys to the dictionary, then read about OrderDict in the collections module.

Comment: That is not a set; that is a dictionary. It happens to contain sets as values, though. What you get when you loop over the dictionary are the keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the *dict*.items() method.

**items()
    Return a new view of the dictionary’s items ((key, value) pairs). See the documentation of view objects.**

You can do:

```
for k, v in my_set.items():
    print(k, v)
```